# Unity Tilemap layer order sorting [Player in front of and behind tiles] Tree sprite consisting of 4 loose tiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been slowly working myself into Unity2D as i'm branching off from web development. As a result I'm currently stumbling against a rendering issue I've had where in a tilemap i have trees (and multiple other objects in the future with the same style) where one tree is made up of 2x2 tiles. The player needs to walk in front of and behind the tree based off of it's Y value. This works, only is the player counting the tree as 4 separate sprites so it displays the player behind one sprite at a time.

My question is, what would the solution be to properly render the player in front of the tree and behind. The solution needs to be dynamic as to where i can for example, make a player 3 tiles high and still work as intended.

Unfortunately i cannot place images on SO just yet as I've just made this account.

- I have messed around already with the Project graphics settings to where I've changed the transparency sort mode and axis, the axis would be at 0/1/-1 now.
- I've placed the player's layer and the tilemap's on the same layers.
- The Tilemap renderer's mode is individual, according to online guides and possible solutions.

I hope the solution will bring me to a way where i can dynamically add anything like a crate, a barrel of 2 tiles high and anything in that sense where i just have to place them, i wouldn't have a problem if it'd be possible to create one tile which would be 2 tile spaces big.

Comment: If the trees were not part of the tilemap, ie you placed them in afterwards, you could just change the z value of the trees transform. If they value was less than / greater than the player, they would appear to walk infront / behind.

Comment: I've tried using a prefab brush, making the tree a prefab but this wouldn't really be a viable solution to me, as the same result has to be generated for E.G. Buildings, bigger rocks, and more and to implement the many rocks/other objects would just be too much of a workaround (if im correct).
I've set the automatic sorting via the graphics settings already, but that apparently counts single sprites.

Comment: Could you just use multiple tile maps on different layers?

Comment: i already am, still testing to build up experience of course, but my current layout is: 
ground (like background, grass, paths etc)
terrain (water etc so trees and rocks can still overlap it)
objects (Player, enemies, rocks and everything that needs position based layer ordering)
obstacles (For walls in the map, that stuff)
overlays (For when i want an overhang or so on a building going transparent when the player's under it, havent worked this one out)

Comment: If your building overhangs are in a separate tile map, could you just say that when the player collides with that tilemap collider, the tile maps alpha value changes?

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you out: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119734/unity-order-in-z-layer-for-objects

In this proposed solution however, the tree can't be part of the tilemap.

Comment: I've already tried this solution, i could make every tree, stone and other buildings a prefab using a prefab brush but this would probably be too big of a workaround as it'd practically replace the tile system into a prefab system.
Any other ideas? i hope there is a way to make tiles which in dimensions, are bigger than one tile (like a tree being one tile, like a prefab brush does but for just tiles)

Comment: Another option is to define where the collider of the tree is. All tiles of the tree, which are within the collider, are behind the player/character (have a "lower" sorting layer) and all the other tiles of the tree are in front of the player. To do this, you need two different tilemaps: one for the Blocking tiles and another one for the "unblocking" tiles. The Advantage is that all existing objects like tree, house and pillars consist of clearly defined blocking tiles and unblocking tiles, and that a tilemap collider can be attached to the tilemap "BlockingTiles".